Confusing overload resolution for SaveChangesAsync
I have two methods in my EF context class, one is an override and one is a new member like this:
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)

...
    public virtual async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(string userId = "")

Why are all calls like await context.SaveChangesAsync() resolving to the second one? Why are they not considered part of same method group by VS C# language service? Why are these calls not causing any ambiguity for the compiler?
When I tried adding new to the second method, thinking that it was hiding the base method, the compiler complained that the modifier was not needed.

The simple (admittedly not especially helpful) answer for your case is, because the specs allow the compiler to prefer one over the other. The spec for overload resolution, which includes the concept of selecting the so called better function member can be found in the csharplang Repo on Github here.

This question is similar to: Overload resolution and virtual methods. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is SaveChangesAsync(string userId = "") method that you have defined on you concrete inheritor of DbContext (assuming that (CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
is the "build in" one)?

@IvanPetrov I think my issue is the same as the question you linked to is addressing. I'll close mine linking to that one, but I must say that rule is confusing. Anyone releasing their product without testing after they upgraded a dependency is out of their mind, and brittle base class would be the least of their problems.

@TanveerBadar I read Eric Lippert's blogs too (that actually answer why) but was more convinced than you. Maybe I haven't thought of all the cases that might be problematic.
